# Is there a means to combine the similar chunks of Vuejs code shown below?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently working on a project and very recently came across Vuejs. I used it to create a dynamic form on my frontend, however, the approach I took does not seem right to me. Could someone take a look and provide some feedback?

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '.directionsContainer',
    data: {
        directions: [
            {
                direction: ''
            }
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        addDirectionForm: function(){
            this.directions.push({
                direction: ''
            })
        },
        deleteDirectionForm: function(directionIndex){
            if(index != 0)
                this.directions.splice(directionIndex, 1)
        }
    }
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: '.ingredientsContainer',
        data: {
            ingredients: [
                {
                    ingredient: ''
                }
            ]
        },
        methods: {
            addIngredientForm: function(){
                this.ingredients.push({
                    ingredient: ''
                })
            },
            deleteIngredientForm: function(ingredientIndex){
                if(index != 0)
                    this.ingredients.splice(ingredientIndex, 1)
            }
        }
})
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with vue.js, but perhaps you could expand upon what & why this doesn't seem right to you. These look to be two discrete components with functions that *look* similar but because of the simplicity of them I can't say it's *actual* code duplication.

I have only a couple significant comments about each deleteX functions

```
deleteDirectionForm: function(directionIndex){
  if(index != 0)
    this.directions.splice(directionIndex, 1)
}
...
deleteIngredientForm: function(ingredientIndex){
  if(index != 0)
    this.ingredients.splice(ingredientIndex, 1)
}
```

1. `index` looks to be undefined. Perhaps this is a case where you defined one function, copy/pasted it to the second component, then updated names and just missed it. Maybe it *is* defined somewhere higher up in scope. I will assume you intended this to be one of the function index arguments.
2. Uses ["==" versus "==="](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) The double equals (`==`) will perform a type conversion when comparing two things, i.e. `"5" == 5 // true` whereas triple equals (`===`) won't do the type conversion, so `"5" === 5 // false`. The index is almost certainly going to be a number so you should use `===`. In fact, you should very nearly ***always*** use `===` when doing comparisons unless you have a compelling reason not to.

```js
console.log('5' == 5); // true
console.log('5' === 5); // false
```

3. Javascript variables have a sense of "[truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)" & "[falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)", and all values are considered truthy unless they are one of the following: `0`, `-0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined` and `NaN`. All non-zero integer values are truthy, so when using as condition tests you can simplify the expression.

```js
const directionIndex = 0;
const ingredientIndex = 5;

if (directionIndex) {
  console.log('do direction stuff');
}

if (ingredientIndex) {
  console.log('do ingredient stuff');
}
```

Suggested updated functions:

```
deleteDirectionForm: function(directionIndex) {
  if (directionIndex)
    this.directions.splice(directionIndex, 1)
}
...
deleteIngredientForm: function(ingredientIndex) {
  if (ingredientIndex)
    this.ingredients.splice(ingredientIndex, 1)
}
```

Comment: All your comments were quite helpful and clarified a lot! The reason I felt the code was "duplicated' because of the similarities between both chunks of code. It is my first time using Vuejs so I am unsure if there is a way to combine both those chunks of code into one segment?

Comment: @HossamAlsheikh Yeah, I had considered the same. To combine them into a single function you'd need to change the signature to take the array, in addition to the index, to operate on as well, something like `function(arr, index) { if (index) arr.splice(index, 1); }`. As I said though, I'm completely unfamiliar with vue.js and have no idea if this would match what the `Vue` constructor would accept as an option object for each component.

Comment: I see ok. Thank you very much.